# Issue with trying to limit datatype inputs

Tags: python

Hello I have this issue with a function that I created in python:

```
def intcheck(num)
    if isinstance(num, int):
        return num
    else:
        intcheck(input("Invalid datatype: Input integer only: "))
```

It's supposed to check if the input is an integer, and if it isn't, ask the user for another input, then check that one, ect. ect.

However the code appears to get stuck on the else: statement such that even a correct input will not return, and it will just ask for another input indefinitely.

Comment: You need to convert the input to an int

Comment: `import pdb; pdb.set_trace(); print type(num)`

Comment: and you need to `return intcheck(...)` in the `else` branch too - else your function will return `None` in this case.

Comment: Hint: `'1'` is not the same as `1`, `input` always returns a string.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: in Python 2.x, `input()` tries to convert it's value. "Equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt))."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler way is:

```
def is_int(foo):
   try:
      return int(foo)
   except ValueError:
      print('{} is not a number'.format(foo))
      return is_int(input('Please enter a number: '))
```

If you are on Python 2, make sure you use `raw_input` instead of `input`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Python 3.x, `input()` returns a string, so you have to convert it to an int. If you're using Python 2.x, you **really** should be using `raw_input()` instead (Python 2.x `input()` is very unsafe), and since `raw_input()` is the same as Python 3.x `input()`, you also have to convert the string to an int.

In both case, you need to return the result of the recursive call in the `else` clause as shown in other answers.

Now using recursion this way, while possibly "elegant", is not the simplest solution - a good old while loop works as fine and avoids stacking frames (Python don't do tail-recursion optimisation):

```
def checkint():
    while True:
        num = input("your prompt here")
        try:
            return int(num)
        except ValueError:
            print "'{}' is not a valid integer".format(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

You've forgotten that the `input` function returns a `str` object! So, you loop forever in the else of the `intcheck` function. Instead, you could do that:

```
def intcheck(num):
    if isinstance(num, int):
        return num
    else:
        input_string = input("Invalid datatype: Input integer only: ")
        try:
            input_int = int(input_string)
        except ValueError:
            input_int = input_string
        finally:
            intcheck(input_int)
```

Comment: in Python 2.x, `input()` tries to convert it's value. "Equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt))."

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers If the OP was using Python 2.x, he would never have posted his question.

Comment: possibly yes but the question is not explicitely tagged as Python 3, and someone else using Python 2 might read the answers and fail to get the implied context.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Not possibly... How could you get this issue using Python 2 ? Similarly, someone else using Python 2 wouldn't have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Input in Python is *always* loaded as a string, so firstly, you need to convert the input into one. Elegant way is to check it with exceptions: if it is `int`, return it, and if not, ask for another input.

```
def intcheck(num):
    try:
        return int(num)
    except ValueError:
        return intcheck(input("That is not a integer, please enter integer: "))
```

Comment: in Python 2.x, `input()` tries to convert it's value. "Equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt))."

Comment: Since in the question is used `input` I am guessing he is using Python 3.x